# cannot figure out confirm on button press in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I am at a loss here, I have made a page with JavaScript, and I used this for giving a simple confimation dialog

```
<form action="blabla" method="post"  onsubmit="return confirm('Proceed?')">
```

And it works fine. But now, I am trying to put the same thing in my PHP project, but it just doesn't do anything, it just goers right onto the target after submitting, no dialog at all.

Did it get built by the JavaScript language of the first page?

Comment: No, that it JavaScript, and it shouldn't have changed from JSP to PHP, but can you provide an example that demonstrates the issue? [It works fine for me.](https://jsfiddle.net/4xsstvx0/)

Comment: What the way you are submitting form. I mean you are using input type submit or input type button or else ?

Answer (score 0):

In PHP following code of html is used for submitting the form

```
<input type="submit" name="submit"/ >
```

or

```
<button name="submit"> Submit</button>
```

the action you have performed is matter i.e. where to redirect or stay on current page if you are using

```
role="form"
```

it will redirect to current form only.

for getting dialog you can use javascript alert also

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example, I don't get a conformation...

```
    <?php //if name is entered into the form for the first time, or is changed, set cookie and redirect to front page
        if (isset ($_POST["name"])){
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        setcookie("name", $name, time() + 60*60*24*7);
        header("location: index.php");

    }   //if name cookie already exists, display it    
        elseif (isset($_COOKIE["name"])){
        $name = $_COOKIE["name"];

    }  //no name has yet been set = first visit
    else{
        $name = "";
    }

    ?> 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>



<form id="msform" action="settings.php" method="post" onsubmit="return confirm">


 <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Settings</h2>
            <article class="showgig">

        Your name: 

      <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="next action-button" value="Change" />   

  </fieldset>
  <br />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this really the code? Nested `form`s are not OK and also, they are not closed properly. This could lead to blocking of any javascript functionality and then the form might just submit without the `confirm` dialog.

Comment: ah, I had cut off some of it, the form is not supposed to there twice either, must have got copied by mistake

Comment: In your code, you use just `confirm`, which will not work. Change it to `confirm('proceed?')`. Does that work?

Comment: Ah damnit, yeah, I had that stuff on my java page, but I snipped it off and thought I would get a basic window. That was it :)

Comment: OK, glad to be of help.

Comment: *My main problem seems to be getting it embedded in this line   echo '<td><button type="submit" name="delete" class="show-button" value="'.$gig->getId().'">Delete</button></td>';

Comment: I would say it's the form's responsibility to do the submit-checking, you do not need to do that in the button. (Btw. you can also add `code` style in comments using back-tics around the code, see also [this page in the Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting))

Comment: Thanks, the little ` ticks solved it. The thing is, I have two buttons, and I only want a confirmation on one of them (that will delete stuff) but thanks a lot for the advice :)